# kafka SMT keeps failing to extract json field to use as message key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using leneses.io s3 source connector to read json files and trying to set message key using SMT.

Here is the config used for connector on AWS MSK

```
connector.class=io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.aws.s3.source.S3SourceConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=topic_3
connect.s3.vhost.bucket=true
connect.s3.aws.auth.mode=Credentials
connect.s3.aws.access.key=<<access key>>
connect.s3.aws.region=eu-central-1
connect.s3.aws.secret.key=<<secret key>>
schema.enable=false
connect.s3.kcql=INSERT INTO topic_3 SELECT * FROM bucket1:json STOREAS `JSON` WITH_FLUSH_COUNT = 1
aws.region=eu-central-1
aws.custom.endpoint=https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms=createKey
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
transforms.createKey.fields=id
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

I can't get the SMT to work and running into below error

```
[Worker-0d3e3af50908b12ee] [2022-04-13 11:43:08,461] ERROR [dev2-s3-source-connector-4|task-0] Error encountered in task dev2-s3-source-connector-4-0. Executing stage 'TRANSFORMATION' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey'. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter:66)
[Worker-0d3e3af50908b12ee] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [copying fields from value to key], found: java.lang.String
```

*P.s. if the SMT commands were removed from config then json files are being read into kafka topic with no issues (but the message key is empty)*

Comment: You've set `value.converter.schemas.enable=true`... Do your json files have schemas? Without seeing your data, how do we know what fields are available to extract?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no the json file doesn't have schemas, I was originally using `value.converter.schemas.enable=false` but gat exact same error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the the Lenses S3 source connector. What do your JSON files look like, though? The error says the connector is reading strings, which makes sense because you have schemas disabled, and therefore you will be unable to use Connect to extract the ID. You will need to use Kafka Streams/KSQL to parse the JSON to do this

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your response once again! here is how the json looks like `{
 "id": 295,
 "data": [
  {
   "id": 298,
   "name": "Some Description"
  }
 ]
}` can you point to me some resource on how to use Kafka Streams/KSQL to parse the JSON please?

Comment: [KSQL](https://ksqldb.io/examples.html#create-a-stream-over-an-existing-kafka-topic) is easiest, but [Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/code-examples.html) offers more flexibility.

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok I was hoping `value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` would have handled that bit but looks like it doesn't. Thanks for the links I will take a look

Comment: Yes, that _deserializes_ JSON, but it will not "parse it" such that the `createKey.fields=id` will work. Only having `schemas.enable=true` will make the `id` field "known" to the Connect Framework, but for Source connectors, this means there needs to be JSONSchema data in those files.